# Turn on a iOS hotspot without 3G connection

Tags: iphone, ios, tethering

Is it possible to turn on my hotspot on my iPhone 5s (running iOS 8) without wifi or 3G connection?
I would like people to connect to my network to play LAN games while overseas. However, I do not want to turn on my 3G so as to save money from the data charges. Is there any way to turn on your hotspot while your 3G/4G is off without jailbreaking?

Comment: You CAN do this with a machine running OS X.

Comment: @CousinCocaine I have found trouble doing this.

Answer (score 1):

In short, No.

The iPhone's hotspot only works with your carrier, 3G, 4G etc, it doesn't operate over Wifi.

I've never Jailbroken, so I don't know if that would help.